# The meaning of “Let-us-take-and-heave-him-over”

Tags: meaning, literature

> Just when the reasons were drowsy with blood-sucking I heard **the regular—“Let-us-take-and-heave-him-over”** grunt of doolie-bearers in the compound. First one doolie came in, then a second, and then a third. I heard the doolies dumped on the ground, and the shutter in front of my door shook. “That’s some one trying to come in,” I said. But no one spoke, and I persuaded myself that it was the gusty wind. The shutter of the room next to mine was attacked, flung back, and the inner door opened. “That’s some Sub-Deputy Assistant,” I said, “and he has brought his friends with him. Now they’ll talk and spit and smoke for an hour.”

This is from 'MY OWN TRUE GHOST STORY' by Rudyard Kipling.  
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2806/2806-h/2806-h.htm#link2H_4_0002

I can not understand the meaning of the sentence.
the regular—“Let-us-take-and-heave-him-over”

Comment: Doolie or litter bearers belonged to a Hindu guild and there was a tradition of chanting as they carried their loads. The words were not the long English hyphenated phrase Kipling showed; rather that shows the rhythm and intonation.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. The rhythmic chanting is akin to marching soldiers: ***Hup** two three four,...*

Comment: Also sailors used to chant when hauling ropes, etc, to keep everybody coördinated, as the New Yorker would say.

Comment: Thank you so much for your examples. They are so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

As Michael says, it is the sound of the words rather than their meaning that Kipling is indicating.

'Take and heave' seems to have been a common formula in the second half of the C19th.  Dickens uses it in *David Copperfield* (1850), Mrs. Gummidge is handed an old shoe to toss after the departing newly-weds in order to confer luck and prosperity upon them.

> "Come, old gal!" cried Mr. Peggotty. "Take and heave it."

> "if it wasn't for the danger of a scuffle, I'd take and heave you into
> the sea, sink or swim."
> [[Silas the Conjuror](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Boy_s_Own_Magazine/1zJAAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22take-and-heave%22&pg=PA502&printsec=frontcover) in The Boys' Own Magazine. 1865.]

> Henry Boozer: It's no good, Mother. He says you can't "bite his ear"
> for no more liquor.
>  Widow Boozer: The willin'! ('villain'?) Never
> mind. When it's dark, Henery, you take and heave a stone through his
> winder.
> [[The Bulletin](https://nla.gov.au/nla.obj-239837258/view?sectionId=nla.obj-250202910&partId=nla.obj-239843055#page/n11/mode/1up/search/heave), Australia. 19 Dec 1885]

And of course, taking and heaving wounded bodies on and off the doolies is what they did.

Comment: Very interesting answer. It's like: Let's go and do that now. Except I disagree with the sound business...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I understand the usage of the sentence.